# IP adresses of B Class: broadcast

Tags: ip, broadcast

Are the following IP adresses - 168.94.254.255 & 168.94.255.254 - used for broadcast, if they belong to B Class? (The adresses were randomly chosen). I suppose 168.94.255.255 would rather be a broadcast adress, but I'm not sure. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A class B network in CIDR notation is a /16 network. A broadcast address is where all of the host bits are 1. In your case, the last 16 bits would need to be 1 to be a broadcast address.

168.94.254.255 and 168.94.255.254 each have a zero bit in the last 16 bits, so they are not broadcast addresses.

If your class B is subnetted into /24's, then the 168.94.254.255 address may be a broadcast address if 168.94.254.0/24 is the network address.

Comment: Ok, I understood. Talking about subnets, I suppose I'll reach this module later. So, only 168.94.255.255 can be a broadcast adress in a B Class network, excepting subnets. Thanks once more! :)